# How to build microservice GET api in springboot which can take single or multiple parameters as insert in Request url and fetch the data as request

Tags: java, spring-boot

`GET/data/search?` Will return all records

`GET/data/search?name=jhon&add=US` Will return specific records as per request

`GET/data/search? Amount=100` Will return all records specific to amount 100

The client can enter at time above all or some parameters as per his requirements.

Any links to reference code will also do

below is my error and implementation

where my repo method is not getting called it is invoking the service method and printing the sysout of controller and service but not of repo that means it is not calling to repo below is the consol output:
Request param received (sysout)

Inside service method(sysout)

2019-10-15 13:54:30,185 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null

```
@RestController
public class MobileController {


@GetMapping(value="/mobile/search")
public List<MobileResponse> getMobile(@RequestParam Map<String, String> 
 map) {
    MobileService mobileService =new MobileService();
    System.out.println("Request param received");
    map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+":"+v));
    List<MobileResponse> mobiles = mobileService.getAllMobiles(map);
    mobiles.forEach(mobile-> System.out.println(mobile));
    return mobiles;
 }
 }
```

service

```
       @Service
       public class MobileService {


  public List<MobileResponse> getAllMobiles(Map<String, String> map) {

    List<MobileResponse> mobilResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Inside service method");
     MobileRepoIntf repo=null;
    mobilResponseList  = repo.findAllMobiles(map);
    return mobilResponseList;
 }
 }
```

Repo interface

```
 @Repository
 public interface MobileRepoIntf{


List<MobileResponse> findAllMobiles(Map<String, String> map);

 }
```

repo implemantation

```
public class MobileRepository implements MobileRepoIntf {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@SuppressWarnings("uncheaked")

@Override
public List<MobileResponse> findAllMobiles(Map<String, String> map) {
    System.out.println("inside Repo method ");
    String query = "select m.id,h.id, r.id from 
 com.axiomtelecom.assignment.entities.Mobile m, 
com.axiomtelecom.assignment.entities.Hardware 
h,com.axiomtelecom.assignment.entities.Releases r where m.hardware_id = 
h.id AND m.releases_id = r.id";
    List<MobileResponse> mobileList = new ArrayList();
    Query qry = em.createQuery(query);
    System.out.println("Query is "+qry);
    return qry.getResultList();
  }

 }
```

Mobile Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOBILE")
public class Mobile implements Serializable {

//Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mobile.class);

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "brand")
private String brand;

@Column(name = "phone")
private String phone;

@Column(name = "picture")
private String picture;

@Column(name = "sim")
private String sim;

@Column(name = "resolution")
private String resolution;


//@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name ="id")
private Hardware hardware;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Releases releases;

//followed by setter and getter methods
}
```

Hardware Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Hardware")
public class Hardware implements Serializable {

//Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Hardware.class);

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name="audioJacks")
private String audioJacks;

@Column(name = "gps")
private String gps;


@Column(name = "battery")
private String battery;

//followed by setter and getter methods
}
```

Releases entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Releases")
public class Releases implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name="priceEuro")
private long priceEuro;

@Column(name="announceDate")
private String announceDate;

//followed by setter and getter methods
}
```

data.sql file

```
enter code here

drop table if exists Hardware;
CREATE table  Hardware (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    audioJacks varchar(200),
    gps varchar(100),
    battery varchar(200),
);


drop table if exists Releases;
create table If Not exists Releases (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    priceEuro int,
    announceDate varchar(100),
);

drop table if exists Mobile;
CREATE TABLE If Not exists   Mobile (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
 brand VARCHAR(250),
phone VARCHAR(250),
picture VARCHAR(250),
sim VARCHAR(250),
resolution VARCHAR(250),
hardware_id int references Hardware(id),
releases_id int references Releases(id)
  );

 //followed by insert query first for releases,hardware and then for mobile 
 data is inserted as expected in db.
```

Comment: Are you using a framework like JAX-RS or Spring ? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: I am using springboot java 8 postman to test my api and H2 as data base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve it.

You could receive the each query parameter as a method argument:

```java
@GetMapping("/foo")
public ResponseEntity<Foo> getFoo(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
                                  @RequestParam(value = "amount", required = false) Integer amount) {
    ...
}
```

You could receive all parameters as a `Map<String, String>`:

```java
@GetMapping("/foo")
public ResponseEntity<Foo> getFoo(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) {   
    ...
}
```

Or you could define a class for representing the parameters and receive an instace of it as a method argument:

```java
@Data
public class FooQueryParameters {
    private String name;
    private Integer amount;
}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/foo")
public ResponseEntity<Foo> getFoo(FooQueryParameters parameters) {   
    ...
}
```

Comment: @M.R.K I don't know what you mean.

Comment: i have edit my post have implemented as per using the suggestion but i am not able to call my repo class as expected i am getting null pointer exception

Comment: @M.R.K Your new issue is different from the original issue described in your question. If this answer helped you to extract the query parameters, please accept my answer an then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like that:

```
@GetMapping("/data/search")
public YourObject getData(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name, 
                          @RequestParam(value = "amount", required = false) Integer amount){
                          ...
                          }
```

Comment: I think, we can create an object that contains parameter instead of writing Variadic function.